# rspec before :each - how to do on one line instead of do..end block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

My code uses a `before :each` block:

```
before :each do
  @unsorted=[1,5,6,7,4,5,8,4,2,5,2]
end 
it "contains an unsorted an array" do
  test_array = BubbleSort.new(@unsorted)
  expect(test_array.contents).to eq [1,5,6,7,4,5,8,4,2,5,2]
end
```

I'd like the `before :each` code to be inline but using

```
before :each {@unsorted=[1,5,6,7,4,5,8,4,2,5,2]}
```

gives:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_
end (SyntaxError)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When there is a block written as `{}`, Ruby's syntax does not allow omission of the parentheses around the arguments. You need to do:

```
before(:each){@unsorted=[1,5,6,7,4,5,8,4,2,5,2]}
```

Comment: You mean that when there is a block that is designated with `{}` rather than `do..end` the parenthesis are required?  The reason is the higher precedence of the `{}` block compared to the `do..end` block?

Comment: @vgoff Yes. I was not accurate enough. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Added an answer that addresses the reason for why we use parenthesis in this case, and where and why it is allowed. +1 for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One answer was to use `before` instead of `before :each` i.e.

```
before {@unsorted=[1,5,6,7,4,5,8,4,2,5,2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not idiomatic of Ruby, but it is allowed.

```
before :each do puts "something here" end
```

The default argument for `before` I believe is `:each` so you could just leave it out.

The stronger precedence of `{}` blocks as compared to `do..end` blocks will require us to use parenthesis so that the block is not associated with the argument rather than the method.  If the argument were a method that does something with a block it would then be allowed, and perhaps confusing.

Of course, your error is specifically from the parser seeing you are trying to apply a block (the unexpected `{`) to a symbol.

Comment: That maybe the case when you have a method/local variable, but with a symbol literal as in this case, I don't think there is room for it to be taken as a method.